# Behavior of a synchronized method with try and finally

Tags: java, synchronized, try-finally

Assume the following method:

```
public synchronized void a(){
    try{
        System.out.println("a");
        return;
    }finally{
        System.out.println("a, finally");
    }
}
```

I understand that the finally block will still be executed even after the return statement. One can even "override" the return value !
But my question is, will the method be unlocked after the return statement or after finally ?

Comment: That will be unlocked after finally, because after finally only the method call will be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `return` is not executed before `finally` block has finished, and because the entire method is `synchronized`, the lock is not released until after the `finally` block has finished.

If you need to release the lock on exception rather than on returning from the method, you can nest your `synchronized` block inside the `try`/`finally` block:

```
public void a(){
    try {
        synchronized (this) {
            System.out.println("a");
            return;
        }
    } finally{
        System.out.println("a, finally");
    }
}
```

Comment: *"`return` is not executed before `finally` block has finished"*: `return` is executed before the `finally` in the sense that the returning expression is evaluated earlier (and the result, if any, is stored as a return value candidate).

Answer (score 1):

1st of all finally will execute before the return statement....

Secondly the lock will be released only when the thread has finished executing the complete method.. ie(till the end braces of this method), Moreover this lock is of the object, so not only this method, but all the synchronized method in that class are locked.

Comment: *"finally will execute before the return statement"*: see my comment on @dasblinkenlight's anwser

Answer (score 0):

yes it is. It'll wait up to return from function which happen after executing finally block execution.